# PHP cURL JSON Object formatting issues

Tags: php, json, curl

I'm running into an issue with formatting using the curl_setopt functions in PHP. I'm basically trying to re-create the cURL request below, but my code returns a bad request from the server. I'm pretty sure it has to do with poor formatting, but I can't figure out where I went wrong.

```
//This code returns the data back successfully
    curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"bio_ids": ["1234567"]}' http://localhost:9292/program
```

---

```
    <?php //This code returns a bad request from the server
    $bio = array('bio_ids'=>'1234567');
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => 'http://localhost:9292/program',
        CURLOPT_POST => 1, // -d
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $bio,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-Type: application/json'), // -H
    ));
    $resp = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    ?>
```

Comment: In PHP, you're not sending JSON. You need a `json_encode($bio)`. That might be all.

Comment: Oh interesting, I didn't realize it required the array in json object format. Perfect, thank you that solved my issue!

Comment: You're welcome. CURL wants a string of data. Only you know how to format your data into a string. Sometimes it's JSON, sometimes XML, sometimes http query string.

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues:

You need to make sure that the structure of `$bio` matches what you are expected to pass, so the `$bio` declaration needs to be:

```
$bio = array('bio_ids' => array('1234567'));
```

Secondly you need to `json_encode` this data structure before sending it to the server:

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($bio),
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php //This code returns a bad request from the server
    $bio = array('bio_ids'=>'1234567');
    $bio = json_encode($bio);
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => 'http://localhost:9292/program',
        CURLOPT_POST => 1, // -d
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $bio,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-Type: application/json'), // -H
    ));
    $resp = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    ?>
```